# Не работает inline-кнопка, должна дать ответ после нажатия

Tags: python, telebot

Не работает кнопка под текстом, должна дать ответ после нажатия. Но при нажатии кнопки ничего не происходит.

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['command3'])
def main(message):
markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1 больше, чем 2', callback_data='question_2')
    markup.add(item)
    

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback (call):
    if call.message and call.data == 'question_2':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Психотип 1')
```

Comment: нет, нажимаю и ничего не происходит

Comment: выкинула 2 кнопки, но при нажатии ответ не дает все равно(

Comment: Текст вашего вопроса, выше, кнопкой "править" ) Чтобы отвечающим было проще вам помочь - чем меньше лишних деталей, тем легче помогается )

Comment: хорошо, спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Клавиатуру можно сделать в отдельной функции, либо внутри функции, где и будет использоваться эта клавиатура
def inline_kb():
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    item = types.InlineKeyboardButton('1 больше, чем 2', callback_data='question_2')
    return markup.add(item)


@bot.message_handler(commands=['command3'])
def mes(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Вопрос", reply_markup=inline_kb())


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_question(call):
    if call.data == 'question_2': # не понял для чего вам тут call.message
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Психотип 1')
        bot.answer_callback_query(callback_query_id=call.id) # для того, чтобы остановить загрузку inline-кнопки
```